# Why can't I use javascript array rest destructuring both ways?

Tags: javascript, babeljs

I've been using and loving babel (6.5.2) for a while now and find the new [destructuring syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) great for writing clearer JavaScript.

Why doesn't the rest destructuring work (it generates a token error) anywhere in the array?
For example:

```
          const [column, ...restOfColumns] = columns;
          const objProps = column.valueChain.slice(0, -1);
          const prop = column.valueChain[column.valueChain.length - 1];
          //const [...objProps, prop] = column.valueChain
```

The commented out line would replace the preceding two lines with something much easier to read and understand.

Comment: The word **rest** should be the hint: it can only be used for the rest of the array.

Comment: In general, when arbitrary-length data is used, it's at the end of something, so they didn't design a full pattern matcher.

Comment: The easy answer would be [because the spec says so](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-destructuring-assignment).

Comment: Thanks @Timo, I've raised this on es-discuss@mozilla.org to see if I can get the spec to say different in future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simple answer is that when you use the destructing syntax `...`, it means everything else.  Therefore when you try `[...objProps, prop]`, it doesn't know what to assign to `prop` as you have assigned all values already to `objProps`

Comment: The `...` syntax already works the way I suggest for objects. It is very handy being able to e.g. `{x: 'x_default', ...original_object, ...object_revisions}` for example. The ability to similarly construct and deconstruct lists is not just cool (although it is very cool), it is also logical and natural `[first, ...rest, last]` reads clearly and naturally for me.

Comment: This is a good answer, although I think the behaviour should be as posted in the question - changing it will mean a change to the specification in future.